# How should I think of statements like "x = 0" in the context of first order theories?

Tags: first-order-logic

I recently started reading *Mathematical Logic* by Joseph R. Shoenfield, and he wrote the following under the section on variables and quantifiers, in the chapter on first order theories:

> If the universe is the set of natural numbers, we can assert that every natural number is equal to itself
>   by asserting $x = x$. While we can now *assert* that every individual has a certain property, we have no formula which *means* that every individual has this property. To see the disadvantage of this, suppose we assert $x=0$. We would then be asserting, incorrectly, that every natural number is equal to $0$. We might hope to make this into a correct assertion by placing $\lnot$ in front. But to assert $\lnot(x=0)$ is to assert that every natural number is unequal to $0$.

He then goes on to say that by introducing $\forall$, we can assert $\forall x(x=0)$, which means that every natural number is equal to zero. Then by negating it, we get $\lnot \forall x(x=0)$, which correctly asserts that not every natural number is equal to zero.

I understand why asserting $x=x$ is the same as asserting that every natural number is equal to itself, and I can also see why asserting $x=0$ is like asserting every natural number is equal to zero. But I don't understand why asserting $\lnot (x=0)$ is asserting that every number is unequal to zero. The only way that I can see how that would work is if $x=0$ doesn't mean "for all $x$, $x=0$", but instead was like the list "$x=0$, $x=1$, $x=2$, ...", and by negating it, $\lnot (x=0)$ becomes the list "$x\neq 0$, $x \neq 1$, $x \neq 2$, ..."

If that's the case, then what makes the first list different from "$\forall x (x=0)$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a convention that if you are in a context where you expect a sentence (with no free variables), and you write a formula with one or more free variables, then it's understood to mean the *universal closure* of that quantifier, where you prefix the formula with $\forall y$ for each free variable $y$.

So if you assert the "sentence" $\lnot(x = 0)$, then since $x$ is a free variable, that is to be understood as asserting $\forall x (\lnot(x=0))$, which you can read as "every $x$ is unequal to 0".  (And of course this assertion is false, as witnessed by $x=0$.)

There is no way to write the sentence "there exists an $x$ which equals 0" as the universal closure of a formula without quantifiers, so this motivates the need for both $\forall$ and $\exists$, and the ability to apply further logical connectives to formulas with quantifiers.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to say. So I can think of $x = 0$ as $\forall x (x = 0)$? But don't these mean different things, since negating them results in different sentences?

Comment: I'm not saying you should think of them as *always* the same.  I'm saying that if you see $x=0$ in a context where it doesn't make sense for $x$ to be a free variable, then you interpret it as the sentence $\forall x (x = 0)$.  It's true that if you interpret both $x=0$ and $\lnot(x=0)$ in this manner, then the sentences you get are not the negations of each other, and that is something you have to get used to.

Comment: Ah, i see - that clarifies things a lot. Thank you so much!